# Equation of the tangent to $4x^2-3xy-y^2=25$ at $(2, -3)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, implicit-differentiation

I have a function $f(x,y)=4x^2-3xy-y^2=25$ and I am trying to find the gradient at $(2,-3)$. First i took the derivative: $$\frac{d}{dx}(f'(x,y))=8x-\left(3y+3x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-8x+3y}{-3x-2y}=\frac{-16-9}{{-6+6}}=\frac{-25}{0}$$

What is going wrong here? After I get the gradient right, do I put it in $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, where $m$ is the gradient?

Comment: Oh, by the way, the answer is supposed to be: $5x-2y=16$

Comment: Apart from a typo in $\frac{d}{dx}(f'(x,y))$ instead of $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x,y))$, your computation is correct.

Comment: @AméricoTavares, but how can the equation have a gradient if it is divided by zero?

Comment: The function is a rotated hyperbola, the point (2, 3) is on the hyperbola, and the tangent **is** vertical at that point.  As stated, you're right, the supplied answer is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean (2,-3), as in my question?

Comment: The tangent to the graph of the curve at $(2,-3)$ is the vertical line $x=2$.

Comment: @hans Yes (2, -3)  My bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is correct, and it seems that your suggested answer is wrong.  When the value of the slope is undefined, this points to the possibility that the tangent line is vertical.  This is the case for your problem, so the tangent line should be x=2.

To see this more rigorously, you could consider $x$ as a function of $y$ and calculate $\frac{dx}{dy}$ at $(2,-3)$.  You should get $0$.  Then use this 'gradient' in the equation $m(y-y_1)=x-x_1$.

If the answer you've listed is correct, perhaps you have copied the problem down incorrectly.